# How to use ModelBinders with DbContext stored in OwinContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I have a simple model binder:

```
public class PersonBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // ...
        // id = routevalues[ id ]

        var db = controllerContext.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();

        return db.Set<Person>().FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == id);
    }
}
```

And it works fine. Here for example:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Person entity, int? id)
{
    if (entity == null && id.HasValue)
        throw new HttpException(404, "Person not found.");

    return View(person);
}
```

The issue is when I try to save it on the database:

```
// DbContext = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>()

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(Person entity, int? id)
{
    if (entity == null && id.HasValue)
        throw new HttpException(404, "Person not found.");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        // WORKS when inserting a new person to the database
        if (!id.HasValue)
            DbContext.People.Add(entity);
        else
        {
            // if I try to attach I get an error: see bellow
            // if I don't attach, it does nothing
        }

        await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    return View(entity);
}
```

Error on attach:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Attaching an entity of type '..Person' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

The entity status shows as `Detached` when I run this in the controller action:

```
DbContext.Entry(entity).State
```

Why does it happen? How could I fix it? Is it not possible to use binders for this?

Comment: The problem that your DbContexts are 2 different instances. How do you get DbContext object into OWIN and how do you get it in controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before doing an Attach, what if you detach the existing entity? Something like: (not tested - sorry this is based on some code in an old project where we had to do something similar for different reasons, but hopefully gives the idea)

```
    if (!id.HasValue)
        DbContext.People.Add(entity);
    else
    {
        var attachedEntity = DbContext.People.Find(id);
        if (attachedEntity != null && DbContext.Entry(attachedEntity).State != EntityState.Detached)
        {
            DbContext.Entry(attachedEntity).State = EntityState.Detached;
            // You may need to recursively detach child entities here if any
        }
        DbContext.People.Attach(entity);
        DbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified; 
    }
```

---

**EDIT:**

Since the main issue seems to be that the instance of your DbContext are different, which makes sense give that the documentation for `IOwinContext.Get<T>` says "Gets a value from the OWIN environment, or returns default(T) if not present."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn270607(v=vs.113).aspx

, can you somewhere (I've not used OWIN much so not sure where the best place would be - but I'd guess at the beginning of your pipeline) call `IOwinContext.Set<ApplicationDbContext>` and pass it a new DbContext so that your 2 calls to HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get() share the same instance?

Comment: This does work. But then I have one more roundtrip to the database, that is something I would like to avoid if possible. (1. Binder goes to the database; 2. My service goes again to detach then attach)

Comment: I guess it doesn't share the same instance so it is not possible to do it in a single shot

Comment: Ah OK, I see your issue now. Hmm, can you not inject the same DbContext instance into your controllers through whatever you're using for IoC?

Comment: The initial Owin setup sets that in the application start. I think it is not possible to use the same Owin context in this scenario. I will accept and award your answer because the first method works very well. Going twice to the db is not a big deal for most cases in this application, so it is fine.

Comment: So you're getting a different OWIN context, or just different DBContext?  I'm curious, what does your OWIN setup look like?

Answer (score -1):

When you are editing, set the entity state as modified before saving.

```
DbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

As it is now entity framework isn't tracking this entity so you need to explicitly specify that this is a modified entity before trying to save it.

Another way would be to retrieve the entity from the database so entity framework tracks it. Then you change it's values with the modified values and when you do that entity framework will notice it and set it as modified automatically. You can then save the changes.

Comment: If I do that I get: `An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Attaching an entity of type 'xxx' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values...`